# C++ type of an object initialized with parenthesis

Tags: c++, types, initialization

I've made a Class with name Matrix. This class has two constructor, one default constructor and one copy constructor. In addition there is a public method called Determinant .In main I write :

```
Matrix a(); 
a.Determinant()
```

or

```
Matrix a(); 
a->Determinant()
```

But none of them is valid.
I print the type of the a but I can't understand what type is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is C++'s most vexing parse. The line:

```
Matrix a();
```

Is interpreted as a declaration of a function that accepts no arguments and returns a `Matrix`. The proper way to create a default constructed object is simply

```
Matrix a;
```

Comment: The error at the two examples is not at line 1 but at line 2. So, why ?

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis Yes, this is the expected behavior. Line 1 is correctly declaring the function `a`, but then you are trying to call the `a.Determinant()` method. Functions in C++ don't have methods. If you implement the correction in the answer, the error in line 2 should go away.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
Matrix a();
```

declares a function returning a Matrix, not an object with default construction. Omit the parentheses.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse for discussion of a more difficult case. (This has to be a duplicate, but a quick search didn't turn one up. I'll look harder in a minute.)

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate as I did find a concise discussion of the same question.